# If $a>b$, then there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $a-\varepsilon>b$

Tags: analysis, inequality, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that, if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ are such that $a>b$, then there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $a-\varepsilon>b$. My approach is as follows:

Suppose not. Then $a-\varepsilon \leq b $ for all $\varepsilon>0$. Define a sequence $a-1/n$. Then $a-1/n\leq b$ for all $n$. So then, by the fact that limits preserve weak inequalities, $a\leq b $—a contradiction.

I am not able to find another way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: $\epsilon=(a-b)/2$

Comment: FWIW your approach is correct, though the easier proof is the direct one. +1 for a well asked question, and I don't understand the close vote, whoever cast it.

Comment: @dxiv Perhaps that the close vote is due to the same user who criticized [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4220590/446262).

Answer (score 3):

You can simply take $\varepsilon=\frac{a-b}2$. Then\begin{align}a-\varepsilon>b&\iff a-\frac{a-b}2>b\\&\iff2a-(a-b)>2b\\&\iff a+b>2b\\&\iff a>b,\end{align}which is true.

Comment: @OliverDiaz *How* is it that a question with a problem to which the OP provides a correct solution can go  against our quality standard policy? Do you claim that it lacks context? Or that it lacks effort?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Care to elaborate what part of the quality standard you have in mind? This is a question I [up](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220589/if-ab-then-there-exists-some-varepsilon0-such-that-a-varepsilonb/4220590#comment8763956_4220589)voted yesterday for being better asked than most, and I do stand by that assessment.